# Rstudio car package MacOsX HighSierra non-zero exit status?

Tags: r, rstudio

I used `install.packages("car", dependencies = TRUE)` which in theory should fix all of the problems with dependencies but these are the errors I got:

```
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘yaml’ ...
** package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘yaml’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/yaml’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘yaml’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
** package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/digest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘sourcetools’ ...
** package ‘sourcetools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sourcetools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/sourcetools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sourcetools’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘later’ ...
** package ‘later’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘later’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/later’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘later’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘coxme’ ...
** package ‘coxme’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘coxme’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/coxme’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘coxme’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘car’ ...
** package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘haven’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependency ‘later’ is not available for package ‘promises’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/promises’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘promises’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependency ‘yaml’ is not available for package ‘htmlwidgets’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/htmlwidgets’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘htmlwidgets’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependency ‘yaml’ is not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/knitr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘car’, ‘effects’ are not available for package ‘alr4’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/alr4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘alr4’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘promises’, ‘later’ are not available for package ‘httpuv’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/httpuv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘digest’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’ are not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependency ‘shiny’ is not available for package ‘miniUI’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/miniUI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘miniUI’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘shiny’, ‘miniUI’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘knitr’ are not available for package ‘manipulateWidget’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/manipulateWidget’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘manipulateWidget’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘knitr’, ‘shiny’, ‘manipulateWidget’ are not available for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please format your question so that it's easier to read. Walls of text make helping you much more difficult

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first, and most obvious error is the `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path`. It looks like there's a fix for that [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path).